# How to use interfaces in exception handling

Tags: c#, generics, interface, code-reuse

I'm working on the exception handling layer for my application.

I have read few articles on interfaces and generics. I have used inheritance before quite a lot and I'm comfortable with in that area.

I have a very brief design that I'm going to implement:

```
public interface IMyExceptionLogger
{
   public void LogException();

   // Helper methods for writing into files,db, xml
}
```

I'm slightly confused what I should be doing next.

```
public class FooClass: IMyExceptionLogger
{

   // Fields
   // Constructors

}
```

Should I implement `LogException()` method within `FooClass`? If yes, than I'm struggling to see how I'm better of using an interface instead of the concrete class...

I have a variety of classes that will make a use of that interface, but I don't want to write an implementation of that interface within each class.

In the same time If I implement an interface in one class, and then use that class in different layers of the application I will be still using concrete classes instead of interfaces, which is a bad OO design...

I hope this makes sense.

Any feedback and suggestions are welcome.

Please notice that I'm not interested in using net4log or its competitors because I'm doing this to learn.

Thank you

**Edit:**

Wrote some more code. So I will implement variety of loggers with this interface, i.e. `DBExceptionLogger`, `CSVExceptionLogger`, `XMLExceptionLogger` etc. Than I will still end up with concrete classes that I will have to use in different layers of my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot avoid having concrete classes implementing IMyExceptionLogger. However, you can stop the classes that need to do exception logging from having dependencies on those concrete classes. That is what the interface is for. So you inject the logger as a dependency of all classes that need to use it:

```
class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(IMyExceptionLogger exceptionLogger)
    {
        ....
        exceptionLogger.LogException(e);
    }
}
```

You could also look into some IoC containers such as [Unity](http://unity.codeplex.com/) to help you manage these dependencies more easily.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the reply.

This means that I will store an interface in one DLL and implementations of that interface in seperate DLLS. This way I'll have various layers referencing single interface layer. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Define an interface Logger and define as many concrete implementations as you want (implementing it).

Next use composition - each class that needs to log something should have a Logger injected into it (via ctor argument or a setter).

This sounds more natural to me.

Answer (score 1):

yes you have to implement  LogException() method in the FooClass.

Advantage of interfaces in your case that you may create concrete type of the logger (FooClass, or DBExceptionLogger  or so) and pass around only IMyExceptionLogger reference. So that all your classes which log info will be independet from concrete realization of logger.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an interface say IExceptionLog. If concrete clases have much in common e.g. XmlLogger, SOAPLogger you can create a base class for those. In classes where you want to use the logger a member having type IExceptionLog(the interface) should be created. The value of this member is set using dependency injection. You can use if you want a [IoC containter](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOfNETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx)

Comment: Everything up to dependency injection makes perfect sense. I'm going to read the article you have provided to get a better idea of what you mean. Thank you!

Comment: I've looked through the list of dependency injection libraries but I think I need to research more to get an idea of what it is and how do I use it.

Comment: You can check this if you want http://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/archive/2008/02/14/understanding-ioc-container.aspx